# Cannot find Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2

Although this might seem like a redundant question, I already tried all the answers I could find on here and none of them worked for my case:

I have a new HP laptop with Windows 10 preinstalled. I created unallocated space with Windows diskmgmt and installed Ubuntu 18.04 with the "install alongside" option.
Now I can not find a way to boot Ubuntu.

I have legacy boot disabled and secure boot enabled, and changing this made no difference. In the UEFI boot order options there is no choice of Ubuntu, and I can not get into grub. I tried `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` in Windows to no avail. 
I then tried using Ubuntu off the Live USB (for which I needed a `nomodeset`) option, to run `boot-repair`, but that did not work either. I then tried reinstalling grub using the method presented in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing under "via LiveCD terminal". However here I am not sure which disks and partitions to use, as my disks are labeled as `/dev/nvme...` and not `/dev/sd...` . Here is my `fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5429963C-036C-4BFB-8C0D-B713D1867C29

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296  589567999 589000704 280.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 999168000 1000198143   1030144   503M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 589568000  999167609 409599610 195.3G Linux filesystem
```

Then using

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt 
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/nvme0n1
```

Gave me the following error:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

I hope this is all the relevant information and I would really appreciate some pointers at what else I might try, thanks.

Edit:

I turned hibernate off in Windows in the beginning.
The other suggested way of installing grub resulted in the following, after which I could still not find Ubuntu or grub.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
root@ubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
Installation finished. No error reported.
root@ubuntu:/# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
root@ubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
GPT:0x3b9e00ef != 0x3b9e12af
GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
Installation finished. No error reported.
root@ubuntu:/# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Edit:
It works now, maybe another reboot did the trick or some automated gparted wizardry.

Comment: Install os-prober mount Windows partition and update GRUB. Maybe can help.

Comment: @sistematico I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean. Could you explain more?